# ASP.net MVC RenderAction and Route

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a web project using ASP.net MVC3. There's an child action in my project. I use

```
<% Html.RenderAction("Navigator", "Application");%>
```

to call a shared action. But I find that if my current url is "localhost/application", it throws an exception "No route in the route table matches the supplied values". But when current url is "localhost/application/index", it works fine. Index is a default action in my route config, which is shown below:

```
    public static void RegisterRoutesTo(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{*favicon}", new { favicon = @"(.*/)?favicon.ico(/.*)?" });
        //routes.IgnoreRoute("{*chartName}", new { chartName = @"(.*)?Chart.aspx" }); //ignore request for charting request
        routes.Ignore("{*pathInfo}", new { pathInfo = @"^.*(ChartImg.axd)$" });

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",                                              // Route name
            "{controller}/{id}/{action}",                          // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },  // Parameter defaults
            new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint("GET", "POST") }   // Allowed http methods
        );
    }
```

Note that I switch default id and action position. I see mvc can remove the default controller and action name in url when using "Html.ActionLink(...)". And I don't like to use explicit url string in my views. How can make it work?

My Action code is simple:

```
    [ChildActionOnly]
    public ActionResult Navigator()
    {
        return PartialView(appFacility.GetAll());
    }
```

Thanks alot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Wrong route URL definition and defaults combination

The problem is that you can't have non optional parameters after an optional parameter.

Why does `localhost/application/index` work? This are route values:

- controller = `"application"` (supplied from URL)
- id = `"index"` (supplied from URL)
- action = `"Index"` (supplied as route default)

Basically these values equal to `localhost/application/index/index` request URL.

If you'd like your `RenderAction` to work, you'd have to call it this way:

```
<% Html.RenderAction("Navigator", "Application", new { id = 0 }); %>
```

which would equal to `localhost/application/0/navigator` request URL.

But you'll soon find out that your route doesn't work and you'll have to change it (because I suppose you don't like having that additional 0 in your URL). If you provide information how you'd like your route work (or why you've decided to switch `action` and `id`) we can provide an answer that will help you meet your requirements.

Comment: Thanks Robert, I think it is the optional parameter problem. About the url, it is the perference of our team. We more prefer /book/{id}/view than /book/view/{id}. ASFAIK, Stackoverflow is built up with asp.net mvc, and the url is like "question/ask" and "question/12345/edit". I think its more **"RESTful"**. I said that because there're a lot of restful actions result in my project for rich UI. To solve this, I add another route map: "{controller}/{action}/{id}", make id optional, and make the id in "{controller}/{id}/{action}" required. I dont know if it's right but it works ok for now.

Answer (score 1):

Optinal parameters work correctly only on the end of route. Try something like this:

```
routes.MapRoute("DefaultWithID", "{controller}/{id}/{action}",
    new { action = "Index" },
    new { id = "^[0-9]+$" }
);

routes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller}/{action}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
);
```

edit: hopefully fixed :) this version counts on fact that ID will be numeric - without constraint we can't tell whether it would mean action or id, so there couldn't be default action on routes when ID is specified

Comment: I don't think this will work, because the first route will match request of the second route as well. It will just route to `Index` action with some `id` along with it. Basically second route will never get hit.

Comment: Allright, I edited my answer. The only way to make optional parameter on the begining or in the middle of route is to use 2 routes and constraint on one of them

Comment: Thanks Lukas, I did much like your way. add a default map route for non-id request